# How to Expand a Box Size Using jQuery Without affecting Page Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to run a jquery which extends a box(div) without affecting on page layout.Here is a sample
http://themes.ddwebstudios.net/?theme=photon&type=html

As you can see if you mouse over on the small transparent box under the image (accross the page) the box will be slideup without changing the page size.

I know how to use .hide() and .show() or slidedown and slideup functions with a display:hidden; box format but as you know there are some issue here as I would likw to display a portion of box and also I dont want to have any changes on pagelayout

Here is the sample which I tried to figure out how to do it, Can you please take a look at that and let me know how I can add a portion of magicDiv box (5% of top) before the row_3 and extend it to full size using jquery functions without affecting(defarming) the page layout?

http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/nuC69/2/

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The boxes do not change the page size because they use absolute positioning and z-index.

If you inspect the `album-thumbs` div by right clicking on it when it opens, you'll see that it's done with CSS:

[image]

The key elements being:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
```

Additionally, and this wasn't part of your question, you would use `display: none;` to avoid affecting page layout or `visibility: hidden;` to still have the div affect page layout. (`display: hidden;`, as you wrote it, is not valid CSS)

Comment: [Here's a fork of your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/nuC69/3/) that demonstrates a working slide-in div like your example.

Comment: Kato, so do I have to change all CSS settings of my style?

Comment: No, you should try a diff on the CSS from my fiddle and your fiddle; there are only a couple of differences, and the only ones that are critical are the addition of `position: absolute` and `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

Kato is spot on. Here is a little snippet for show hide() portion of jQuery()

Mine is a little different as I like to use arrays to store the height of expanding windows. This allows me to have expanding windows of various heights and less jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //create a string array to store various window sizes then based upon the attribute id of the element


        //load the apporaiate array value
        var winHeight = ["220px",
                         "100px",
                         "90px",
                         "400px",
                         "150px"];

    $(function () {
        $('.div1').hide();
    });

    $('.div2').click(function () {
        var cssProp = winHeight[$(this).attr('id')];

        if ($('.div1').is(':hidden')) {
            $('.div1').show();
            $('.div1').animate({ "height": cssProp }, 'slow');
        }
        else {
            $('.div1').hide("slow");
            $('.div1').animate({ "height": "0px" }, 'slow');
        }
    });
```

The only css applied was

```
.div1
{
    margin: 5px;
    height: 0px;
    font-size: .9em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The value is assigned by picking up the attribute id in the div element

```
<div id="1" class="div2" /> // would set the height to 100px
```

when using hide() it attaches the attribute hidden to the element which is how I am testing to see the "visual" state of the div element.  In this example I have this on a click event but you could change your event logic to .hover() if needed

I have modified [your original jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rlcrews/nuC69/6/) file to show a working example

Comment: Thanks for your comment but honestly I got confused here, where did you get the div1 and where is it's position? I mean in the sample http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/nuC69/2/ page? thanks again

Comment: @Behseini I have updated my answer along with a link to a updated jsFiddle example

Comment: Sorry rlcrews, I did'nt mentioned your solution but This was is not the answer to my question.Can you please take a look at first site I already linked? What I want is not displaying a Hidden or Invisible box. I would like to expand a box which a portion of it already is in the layout and it will re size without changing any thing in my layout.